# How to call "owner" of this polymorphic model in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, polymorphic-associations

```
class Chair < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :buildings, :as => :faculty
end

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :buildings, :as => :faculty
end

class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :faculty, :polymorphic => true
end
```

In routes file I have:

```
resources :departments do
  resources :buildings do
end

resources :chairs do
  resources :buildings do
end
```

How can I build in good way a new Building in one controller for Department and Chair. I know, that I can create another helpful function, that it will check for who create Building:

```
class BuildingsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @parent = faculty
    @building = @parent.buildings.build
  end
end
```

in application_controller:

```
def faculty
  if params[:department_id]
    Department.find(params[:department_id])
  elsif params[:chair_id]
    Chair.find(params[:chair_id])
  end
end
```

but I am asking, is there any other Rail's way to do it? Maybe there exist some method in Rails3 that I can use to get information: Who want's to create building, without implementing another function faculty.

Comment: Why you moved faculty to application controller? Move it to `buildings`.Try to think from the buildings/chairs and buildings/departments, if not, then it's best way how you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you also have to make additional function, but you don't have to make ifs over params list: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

Comment: Thanks Michał for reply. I see that probably there doesn't exist a standard method in rails, which finds "parent" in that cases.

Comment: I am bewildered by the lack of a parent method in rails. Is this really rails, the forward-thinking, quickly-improving, user-friendly, and intuitive framework?